Cut everything that sticks out of the object leaving the inside as is



hello, so i'd like to remove everything from that cuve that sticks out of the cone, i tried boolean difference, but it messes up the inside as well, which id like it to stay as is. I only want to remove everything that intersects with outside walls of the cone, how do i do that?
in last picture i attached effect of selecting cube, then boolean difference on cone.

hello could you please share your file?

I managed to do that, with joining the cube with the cone, selecting all faces of the cube (Ctrl+L) and selecting intersect (knife) from Ctrl+F menu. Then just deleting the faces outside of the cone.

I do not know how using Boolean "messes up the inside as well" and I do not know what the "effect of selecting cube" is, but here is how I understand what you want to do:
My assumption is, you have this 6-sided cone and a cube (or some other kind of object) with a cylindrical hole. And you want the intersection of those two, so keep the part of the cube which is inside with the hole intact and remove that part of the cube which is outside the cone.

In order to achieve that I give a Boolean modifier to the cube object, set it to Intersect and select the cone as the object to intersect with:

Now the question is: if that's not what you want, what is it then? Or if it's that but it's not working for you, we need more information on your objects, are they manifold, are the normals correct etc. and how you've set the modifier and so on...

Yes, you understood perfectly, sorry for not stating it clearly.
it "messes up the inside" as i have shown in the screen attached, i did the thing you suggested, but the outcome of it is as shown in third screen, it doesn't keep the part inside the cone, I don't know why it's not working in my case, I will try the knife thing tho

@mil0s2 Honestly, the Knife tool is a bit tedious in my opinion when the Boolean modifier does exactly what it should in this case. I made some suggestions at the end of my answer why it might not work in your case. As long as you did not check those possibilities or uploaded your file for us to check I would assume you are doing something wrong.

In edit mode, press K (Knife tool) to manually add vertices and edges as you like.
Press Enter after every cut.


Problem was, I couldn't select the intersection point with knife, so it wouldn't be precise
